# please fix code append() and empty()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#stopmusic").click(function(){
                $("#musicbox").empty();
            });
            $("#playmusic").click(function(){
                if ($('#musicbox').visible( true )) {
                    $('#musicbox').append('');
                }  
                else {
                    $('#musicbox').append('<iframe src="youtube_playlist" width="300px" height="60px" scrolling="no" />')
                }        
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <button id="playmusic">Play</button>
        <button id="stopmusic">Stop</button><br>
        <div id="musicbox">
            <iframe src="youtube_playlist" width="300px" height="60px" scrolling="no" />
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

The `empty()` is ok but the `append()` is not working. I want to remove the playlist from my website when the button "Stop" is clicked and show the playlist again when the button "Play" is clicked.

My previous code is not include the if/else so when I click "Play", the playlist appear another, another , another again but i want it appear 1 time and if i click "Stop", it's gone, if i click "Play", it's appear again.

Can anybody help? Please.

Comment: Use .html() instead of using .append()

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manipulating the inner HTML,
you could simply `show` / `hide`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#stopmusic, #playmusic").click(function() {
            $("#musicbox").toggle();
        });

    });
```

I'm not sure if your iframe contains **playable *video* content** (since you've used a pseudo `src`).
In the case you want to stop your iframe from playing:

```
    $(function(){ // DOM ready shorthand

        var $mBox = $("#musicbox");
        var iframe = $("iframe")[0].outerHTML;

        $("#stopmusic, #playmusic").click(function() {
            $mBox.html( this.id==="stopmusic" ? "" : iframe );
        });

    });
```

Note that `<center>` tag is deprecated in HTML5.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/fetipu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it `$(SELECTOR).is(':visible')` more appropriate ? There is no such a function `$(SELECTOR).visible(true)` in jQuery.

```
if ($('#musicbox').is(':visible') {
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#stopmusic").click(function(){
     $("#musicbox").empty();
});
$("#playmusic").click(function(){
     if ($('#musicbox iframe').length < 1) {
         $('#musicbox').html('<iframe src="youtube_playlist" width="300px" height="60px" scrolling="no" />')
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#stopmusic").click(function(){
    $("#musicbox").empty();
});

$("#playmusic").click(function(){
    if ($('#musicbox').html() == '') {
      $('#musicbox').append('<iframe src="youtube_playlist" width="300px" height="60px"        scrolling="no" />')
   }        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#stopmusic").click(function() {
    $("#musicbox").empty();
  });
  $("#playmusic").click(function() {
    $('#musicbox').html('<p>Test</p>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <button id="playmusic">Play</button>
  <button id="stopmusic">Stop</button>
  <br>
  <div id="musicbox">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: with your help above it's working, yep.
But it has a problem, when i press "Play" again the playlist will reload
Anyway, thank you for your answer. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try with below updated script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#stopmusic").click(function(){
            $("#musicbox").empty();
        });
        $("#playmusic").click(function(){
            if ($('#musicbox iframe').is(':visible')) {
                $('#musicbox').append('');
            }  
            else {
                $('#musicbox').append('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/flMDiQib1J4?list=PL7W4kY6q3mxsiAgJNh1BlEWGI3PXBUqju" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
            }        
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    .......
$("#playmusic").click(function(){
                if ($('#musicbox > iframe').length>0) {
                    $('#musicbox').append('');
                }  
                else {
                    $('#musicbox').append('<iframe src="youtube_playlist" width="300px" height="60px" scrolling="no" />')
                }        
            });
.........
```